# Тестирование контроллеров laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Есть метод в контроллере:

```
   public function getById(Country $country)
   {
       return $country;
   }
```

при обращении через браузер все ОК, модель Country нормально подгружается по идентификатору.
В phpunit не подгружается по переданному идентификатору (в $country пустая модель без аттрибутов). Если изменить метод контроллера на

```
   public function getById($country)
   {
       return Country::find($country);
   }
```

то все работает правильно и в phpunit. В Laravel 5.2 такой проблемы не было, пробовал phpunit 4 и 5 версий.

Answer (score 3):

Если вдруг у кого будет такая же проблема - оказалось из-за использования в тестах трейта WithoutMiddleware.